# How to dismiss Interstitial ad programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, admob

I have integrated Interstitial Ad for my iOS app successfully. And I know on that ad view there is a close button and we can dismiss it after clicking that button.

But I want to dismiss this ad view in programmatically after 3 seconds. But I don't know what is the method to dismiss this ad.

**---- UPDATED-----**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    singletonClassObject=[Singleton SharedManager];

    //--------ADMOB FULLSCREEN----------
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;

    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    // Requests test ads on simulators.
    request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" ];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
    //--------END OF AD MOB FULLSCREEN---------
}
```

This is how show the ad in a click event

```
  if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
     [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
  }
```

These are the delegates that fire when app dismiss,shows etc

```
/// Called when an interstitial ad request succeeded.
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidReceiveAd");
}

/// Called when an interstitial ad request failed.
- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

/// Called just before presenting an interstitial.
- (void)interstitialWillPresentScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillPresentScreen");
}

/// Called before the interstitial is to be animated off the screen.
- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillDismissScreen");

    //[viewAdd removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

/// Called just after dismissing an interstitial and it has animated off the screen.
- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidDismissScreen");
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

/// Called just before the application will background or terminate because the user clicked on an
/// ad that will launch another application (such as the App Store).
- (void)interstitialWillLeaveApplication:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillLeaveApplication");
}
```

Comment: Can you share your existing codes?

Comment: I updated the answer with the code

Comment: You can't. There is no dismiss function for `GADInterstitial` class: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/6.11.1/Classes/GADInterstitial.html

Answer (score 9):

although undocumented, I found that interstitial can be dismissed by:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

called on the ViewController presenting the Interstitial

Backward engineering, the Interstitial must be presented by presentViewController:animated:completion:

Comment: Work fine, this save my day!

Comment: you are a lifesaver

Comment: Is there Swift version?

Answer (score 0):

Well Unfortunately it is not possible you can not do that.

Check out this: [Cocoadocs docsets Google Mobile Ads](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/6.11.1/Classes/GADInterstitial.html)